# How to find the peer.adr in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to copy an existing Hbase table from one cluster to another using the below command

```
bash>hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable
--rs.class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ReplicationRegionInterface
--rs.impl=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.replication.ReplicationRegionServer
--starttime=1265875194289 --endtime=1265878794289
--peer.adr=ip-101-41-10-65.ec2.internal:2181:/hbase Test_table
```

however it does not work. The problem is with the peer.adr..
Does any one know how to get the exact peer.adr value from the cluster?
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "it does not work" - Describe the problem a little more. What exactly didn't work? The command, yes, but is there an error message you get? If so, can you please include it in your question?

Comment: The error is in the peer.adr that says invalid peer address. I need to know if I am supplying the right address. How to get the peer address of the HBase in a cluster.

Comment: According to some documentation I found, peer.adr should be the Zookeeper quorum, it isn't something Hbase specific